# django rest framework list update api view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add update options to the list items. So that if anyone perform 'PATCH' request to it I will get the details and update them. This is my code for the implementation

```
class SwitchListView(UpdateModelMixin, ListAPIView):
  serializer_class = serializers.SwitchSerializer
  lookup_field = 'home_id'

  def get_queryset(self):
    home_id = self.kwargs.get('home_id', None)
    if home_id is None or int(home_id) < 0 or \
            self.request.user.pk != models.Home.objects.filter(pk=home_id)[0].user.pk:
        return models.Switch.objects.none()
    query = models.Switch.objects.filter(home=models.Home.objects.filter(pk=home_id))
    return query

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(SwitchListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

  def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Came here")
    data = request.data['data']
    for i in data:
        query = self.get_queryset().filter(i['pk'])
        if query.exists():
            query.switch_status = i['switch_status']
            query.save()

    return Response({'message': 'successfully updated switch!'})
```

But here the request to the api is only accepting GET, HEAD and OPTIONS. I even tried adding `http_method_names = ('get', 'patch')` but even this is not working!!

Is there any way to put the patch request to the view ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is my implementation, FWIW:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MyListView(viewsets.mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ...
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

    def list_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        instances = list(queryset)
        count = len(instances)
        # TODO perhaps validate for max allowed count, before doing list(queryset) !
        data = [request.data] * count
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            instances, data, many=True, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_list_update(serializer)
        return Response(status=204)

    def perform_list_update(self, serializer):
        for instance, data in zip(
                serializer.instance, serializer.validated_data):
            for attr, value in data.items():
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
            instance.save()
        # alternatively use a queryset.update, but be aware that it will not
        # fire pre_save and post_save signals
```

If you're not using DRF routers (because when doing anything "custom"  like this, using only naked views is usually much more pain-free), edit urls.py like so:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(
        r'^path/to/mymodels',
        MyListView.as_view({
            'get': 'list', 
            'patch': 'list_update',  # <--
        }),
    ),
]
```

If using routers, this little hack works and is simple, but not terribly nice:

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.routes[0].mapping['patch'] = 'list_update'  # <--
...
```

It might also makes sense to override `get_serializer_class` on the viewset to have a different serializer for list_update action.

Comment: I tried this.  It looks like it will bulk update every record to have a specific value.  Is there any way to pass in a list of primary keys and make the update happen for each pk.  or potentially pass in a list of dictionaries with updates for each type and then parse it on the back end and update all of the records in 1 request?

Comment: Yes, this is for the "bulk update" situation. Parsing a list with multiple payloads should not be difficult, but the tricky part is how to be confident that those payloads are applied to the objects as intended (e.g. what if an object got deleted between initial reply and the PATCH request). YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I based my version on frnhr's but didn't want to use `GenericViewSet`. I also tried to make it conform a bit more to the existing generic views, using `put` and `patch` so I wouldn't need to mess with routers.

```
class FooBulkUpdateAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooBulkUpdateSerializer

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instances = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        data = [request.data] * instances.count()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instances, data, many=True, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(status=204)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        for instance, data in zip(serializer.instance, serializer.validated_data):
            for attr, value in data.items():
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
            instance.save()
```

Comment: Nice answer. But I am just wondering if ListAPIView has all these method on it or it has just list method on it?

Answer (score -2):

```
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

...

@detail_route(methods=['put', 'patch'])
def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

try it?